# I want to change the color of my navigation button when certain DIV is active

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I want to achieve is that when the first swiper-slider div is active, that the first button of the navigation div is ALSO active. Then, I can change the background color for that navigation circle.

So, what already works is that when I scroll down that the next slider-wrapper becomes active. The only think I need to do is link an active slider-wrapper to the corresponding circle of the navigation menu.

Looking for help!

```css
.swiper-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    background: #fff;

    /* Center slide text vertically */
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.sections {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}



.foto1{
    background:
    linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)),
    url(images/beren.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;

}
.foto2{
    background:
    linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)),
    url(images/adventure.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.foto3{
    background-image: url(images/eekhoorn.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.foto4{
    background-image: url(images/beren.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}


.navigatie-front {
    position: absolute;
    left: 95%;
    top: calc(50% - 160px);
    height: auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    a {
       width: 50px;
       height: 50px;
       background-color: #f00;
       border-radius: 50%;
       margin: 15px 0px;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://arwinblog.localhost/arwinblog.localhost/wp-content/themes/nieuw/main.js"></script>

<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="foto1 sections"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div id="scroll" class="foto2 sections"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="foto3 sections"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="foto4 sections"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="navigatie-front">
    <a id="button1"></a>
    <a id="button2"></a>
    <a id="button3"></a>
    <a id="button4"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]
I cant come up with anything, CSS or JS, that can solve this problem

Comment: Have you considered making an `active` class and loading the page with the first element set to have the active class? Then upon changing images in your carosel, you would update your nav to remove the active class from the current element and move the active class to the new nav element.

Comment: @Shmack Yes, but how to achieve that is difficult haha. In the meanwhile i solved my problem, since what i wanted was already integrated in the swiper-budle javascript package.